# Реализация рекурсии в классе

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь релизовать рекурсию в классе, метод binary search:

```
def search (self, target_item):
    if self.counter == 0:  
        return False
    else:
        mid = self.counter // 2

        if self.str_list [ mid ] == target_item:
            return True

        elif target_item < self.str_list [ mid ]:
            smaller_list = self.str_list [ :mid ]
            return search ( smaller_list, target_item )

        else:
            smaller_list = self.str_list [ mid + 1: ]
            return search ( smaller_list, target_item )
```

Возвращает ошибку:

`in search
    return search ( smaller_list, target_item )
NameError: name 'search' is not defined`

Понимаю что вызов функции с помощью return работает не верно, какой должен быть return?

Comment: return self.search(...)

Comment: @vadimvaduxa возвращает ошибку TypeError: search() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: self это ссылка на инстанс класса в котором находится метод search  | search  принимает один аргумент (self, target_item), вы передаете два - ( smaller_list, target_item )

Comment: @vadimvaduxa но мне же вместо self.str_list требуется передать smaller_list...

Comment: у вас метод принимает ОДИН аргумент, вы передаете ДВА

Comment: @vadimvaduxa я это понял. в таком случае, как мне лучше реализовать рекурсию?

Comment: очевидно, добавить в функцию второй агрумент smaller_list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Myclass:
    def search (self, target_item, smaller_list=None):
        if smaller_list is None:
            pass
        elif smaller_list > 0:
            print(target_item)
        else:
            return self.search(target_item, smaller_list)
```